# Robot framework Selenium2Library get WebDriver instance

Tags: python, selenium, testing, robotframework

In Robot Framework, is it possible to get the WebDriver instance from the Selenium2library and use it in Python code? What I wanna do is extend the Selenium2Library with some custom functions. But I need the WebDriver instance to do that.

Comment: Selenium2Library is very old and unsupported. Is there a reason you're using it rather than the newer SeleniumLibrary?

Comment: @BryanOakley no reason, i'm pretty new to Robot framework and i thought SeleniumTWO was the new library :D I didn't specifiy any library in my robot file so I assume it's using the SeleniumLibrary then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium2Library is no longer supported. The newest version of robot's selenium library is [SeleniumLibrary](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-seleniumlibrary/). If you are using `SeleniumLibrary` rather than the outdated `Selenium2Library`, you can access the actual webdriver instance like so:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
selib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance("SeleniumLibrary")
driver = selib.driver
```

This is documented in the SeleniumLibrary source code repository in the file [docs/extending/extending.rst](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/blob/master/docs/extending/extending.rst)